# How to debug Azure VM extension?

Tags: azure, powershell, azureportal

I have created custom extension for my Azure VM with powershell.
Its stopping in-between and I'm not able to see in serial logs why it failed, where I can find debug logs for my extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the VM console output for the custom script extension can be found in a json file located at :
`C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.9\Status`

Azure command execution and script handling logs (ie logs detailing the downloading and running the script) can be found at :
`C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension\1.10.9`